# fastest way to change checksum of jar file without unzipping it or preventing it from executing

Tags: java, jar, zip, md5, checksum

I would like to **generate a jar file with a custom checksum from an existing executable jarfile** in java
(for example, md5 =  PIZZA3jof43U3q5bG...)

This should happen without breaking the jar, and without having to unzip+rezip and/or rehash the entire file for every checksum I look through.

Ideally, there would be a way for me to increment an irrelevant section of bytes as close to the end of the jar as possible, allowing me to step through checksums with minimal effort (only having to rehash the last n bytes of the file instead of the entire file)

So far all I have tried with jars is appending bytes to the end of the file, and while they can still be opened and viewed like normal zip files, they can no longer be executed.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible to achieve, and if so, are there any resources / tips on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends heavily on the checksum function that's being used. E.g. for XOR checksum, this is not hard. But for most of the currently used checksum functions, this is impossible or at least extremely CPU demanding. Even for the MD5 checksum which you mention and which [has severe vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), you'll basically have to try appending different random numbers until you get the checksum you want.

As a side note, checksums are usually hexadecimal numbers so they can only contain letters a-f, not strings like "Pizza".

Also note that when you cannot easily "increment an irrelevant section of bytes" in jar file because it would invalidate the whole archive.

Comment: I am not using this for anything security related, so the "vulnerabilities" are not a concern. and checksums are just a certain amount of bits that can be displayed in either hex or base 64, so that is also not a problem. As far as incrementing an irrelevant section of bytes, I have read that there are metadata sections of zip files where any data can be stored, which is why I was asking if anything remains in the jar format that can be modified without breaking the jar.

Comment: Those security vulnerabilities would allow you to find the desired checksum values faster, that's why I mentioned them.